# How to set data from external callback in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I included some external SDK into my component:

```
mounted() {
    // Load external Script
    let externalScript = document.createElement('script')
    externalScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://x.klarnacdn.net/kp/lib/v1/api.js')
    document.head.appendChild(externalScript)
    ...
```

Later I am receiving a callback like this:

```
authorizeKlarna: function(){  
        Klarna.Payments.authorize({
        payment_method_category: "pay_later"
        }, function(res) {
        console.debug(res);
        if(res.approved == true){ 
            this.token = res.authorization_token
        }
        })
      },
```

However `this.token` will not be updated because I am out of scope. Is there any simple way how to access data of my vue component from this external callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `function(res)` to Arrow Function `(res) =>`

```
authorizeKlarna: function(){  
  Klarna.Payments.authorize(
  { payment_method_category: "pay_later" },
  (res) => {
    console.debug(res);
    if(res.approved == true){ 
      this.token = res.authorization_token
    }
  }
)
},
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you so much!